# How do I convert **Object.days = 256 days** to **256**

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
@days_since_last_payment = 256 days
```

How do I derive the number 256 out of this? It seems if I use a math operation on this, it calculates something other than 256.

It is derived from

```
@days_since_last_payment = (Date.parse(@date_awarded) - Date.parse(@date_paid)).days
```

Comment: I updated above to see its source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you meant `256.days` rather than `256 days`. If so, you can divide by 86400 to get the actual number 256. (It looks like `256.days` is actually stored as 22,118,400 seconds)

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :056 > @days_since_last_payment
 => 256 days 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :057 > @days_since_last_payment.seconds
 => 22118400 seconds 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :058 > @days_since_last_payment.to_i
 => 22118400 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :059 > @days_since_last_payment / 86400
 => 256
```

Comment: Interesting! I also found that @foobar.inspect.to_i does the trick too, but I'm happy to know where it is deriving that number from.

Comment: Yes, `#inspect` just returns a string `"256 Days"`, and running `#to_i` on a string will just parse the string until it hits a non-numeric portion.

Answer (score 0):

regex. I don't know Ruby, but take a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/ruby.html

Basically, you can remove all non-digits by replacing /\D+/gi with ''.